# Filter JSON Data using AngularJS and enlist with ng-repeat using smart tables

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

This is my JSON Data.

```
"ATTRIBS":{

          "WWW":
            {
              HIGH:10,
              LOW:1,
              NAME:World Wide Web, 
              TYPE:ON
            },
          "NET":
            {
              HIGH:12,
              LOW:1,
              NAME: Local Net,
              TYPE:OFF
            }
          }
```

I want to list this JSON data in table (I am using smart tables), where I only want to list data which has TYPE:OFF.

I have tried using filters in ng-repeat but data does not populate.

This is the code I am using for listing in table:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in offAttribs">

        <td>{{value.NAME}}</td>
        <td>{{value.key}}</td> //I want abbreviations here i.e, www,NET..etc 
        <td>{{value.TYPE}}</td>
        <td>{{value.LOW}}</td>
        <td>{{value.HIGH}}</td>
```

This is how my controller looks, it loads JSON data from other services.

When I use offAttribs in ng-repeat using if condition in controller, it just throws key as (index numbers 0,1,2... ) instead of (keys of JSON i.e, WWW or NET....),

edit............. Working code

```
    $scope.offAttribs = [];
    for (var key  in attribData){
          attribData[key]['ABRV'] = key;
            if (attribData[key].TYPE == 'OFF' ) {
                $scope.offAttribs.push(attribData[key]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what appears when you add a div above the ng-repeat?```<div ng-bind="attribData"></div>```

Comment: Have you tried filtering the data in the controller and passing that to the `ng-repeat`? It might end up a bit messy if you put all the logic in the template.

Comment: ng-repeat="(key, value) in attribData | filter: {TYPE: "OFF"}"  did you try this ?

Comment: @MayK Yes, I have tried this with single quote 'OFF' and no table appears, while "OFF" throws 'expression expected' error in my webstorm IDE

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `offAttribs` has the data structure that you expect. Angular's `(key, value) in offAttribs` syntax will only work if `offAttribs` is an object. In your code sample `offAttribs` is an array.

If you want to access the key like WWW or NET you need `offAttribs` to be an object:

```
$scope.offAttribs = {};

for (var key  in attribData){
    if (attribData[key].TYPE == 'OFF' ) {
        $scope.offAttribs[key] = attribData[key];
    }
}
```

TLDR; the keys of an array are its index. that's why you are getting 0,1,2 instead of WWW, NET, etc

Comment: Yes ! It iterates for all 'OFF' values and create empty fields (no value for HIGH,LOW NAME, TYPE....) in table, whereas I have one more <td><input type="number" </td>, which gets listed for all fields.

Comment: does this answer your question?

Comment: No , this gives me all value {NAME TYPE LOW HIGH} but I also want "WWW"  "NET" in another table field under abbreviation, since object is saved in $scope.offattribs.... its sets off the label name as 0,1,2,3....

Comment: added 

   attribData[key]['ABRV'] = key; 
and I got what I want. I am not sure whether its good practice or not.